# Cosmos DB DateTimePart Not Parsing Some Dates

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Cosmos DB seems unable to parse dates with 6-digit fractional seconds, such as `2020-08-25T10:00:14.634466Z`.

Furthermore, I found an interesting pattern:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 
    DateTimePart("yyyy", "2020-08-25T12:01:01Z"),
    DateTimePart("yyyy", "2020-08-25T12:01:01.1Z"),
    DateTimePart("yyyy", "2020-08-25T12:01:01.11Z"),
    DateTimePart("yyyy", "2020-08-25T12:01:01.111Z"),
    DateTimePart("yyyy", "2020-08-25T12:01:01.1111Z"),
    DateTimePart("yyyy", "2020-08-25T12:01:01.11111Z"),
    DateTimePart("yyyy", "2020-08-25T12:01:01.111111Z"),
    DateTimePart("yyyy", "2020-08-25T12:01:01.1111111Z")
FROM c
```

Results:

```
[
    {
        "$1": 2020,
        "$4": 2020,
        "$8": 2020
    }
]
```

Where the only combinations that could even parse the year correctly had 0, 3, and 7-digit fractional seconds.

The documentation for [Cosmos DB DateTimePart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-datetimepart) does seem to assume 7-digit fractional seconds, but I also wouldn't have expected it to fail to parse when the value was rounded.

Short of truncating the string first to eliminate the fractional seconds, is there a better way to work around this issue? Also, is there a way to ensure that the Cosmos SDK for .NET will correctly serialize DateTimes with 7-digit fractional seconds, instead of truncating to 6 digits when the final digit would be zero? In my case, I'm just storing the result of `DateTime.UtcNow`, and some of the values end up with 6-digit fractional seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,you can try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    left( "2020-08-25T12:01:01Z",4),
    left( "2020-08-25T12:01:01.1Z",4),
    left( "2020-08-25T12:01:01.11Z",4),
    left( "2020-08-25T12:01:01.111Z",4),
    left( "2020-08-25T12:01:01.1111Z",4),
    left( "2020-08-25T12:01:01.11111Z",4),
    left( "2020-08-25T12:01:01.111111Z",4),
    left( "2020-08-25T12:01:01.1111111Z",4)
```

If you want to ensure 7 digits,you can change your property type to string and use this code:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fffffffZ")
```

Comment: In my case, I don't really have a good place to do this `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fffffffZ")` because I'm just saving an object into Cosmos DB and the property type is DateTime. I'm guessing I would need to override the Json Serializer settings to accomplish this, but I would have expected the docs to call this out if it was so critical to do.